# The data fields like name, address and images are inserting into the database but the problem is that the image doesn't store to the folder

Tags: laravel, nuxt.js

The data fields like name, address and images are inserting into the database but the problem is that the image doesn't store to the folder.

public function store(Request $request)
{

```
    $image = $request->file('file');
    $imageName = time().'.'.$image->extension();
    $image->move(public_path('images'),$imageName);

    $vendor = new Vendor();
           $vendor->profileimage = $imageName;

    $vendor->save();

    $vendor = $request->validate($this->validation());
    $value = Vendor::create($vendor);
 

    // if request has default vendor request
    if ($request->default_vendor) {
        $request->user()
            ->setting()
            ->update(['default_vendor_id' => $value->id]);
    }

    return $this->respondWithMessage('Vendor successfully saved.');
}
```

Comment: Please post the relevant view code as well where you are uploading the file with form.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check whether you are receiving uploaded file and is it a valid one

Try dd($request->hasFile('file') && $request->file('file')->isValid()) to check.

```php
public function store(Request $request) {

    //Get the validated data from the request
    //Assuming that $this->validation() are the validation rules
    $validated = $request->validate($this->validation());

    //Check whether a valid file has been uploaded
    if($request->hasFile('file') && $request->file('file')->isValid()) {
        
        $image = $request->file('file');
        $imageName = time().'.'.$image->extension();
        $image->move(public_path('images'),$imageName);

        //Add the filename to the validated data array 
        $validated['profileImage'] = $imageName;
    }

    //Create a new Vendor record from the validated data
    //Exclude the file, as we have stored it already
    //And plus the file key contains file binary data
    //And we do not want to store actual file binary/blob data in db
    $vendor = Vendor::create(Arr::except($validated, ['file']));
 

    // if request has default vendor request
    if ($request->default_vendor) {
        $request->user()
            ->setting()
            ->update(['default_vendor_id' => $value->id]);
    }

    return $this->respondWithMessage('Vendor successfully saved.');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First make sure the form type is multipart, and then try to run this command :

```
php artisan storage:link
```